# Jquery $.post return empty value

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I use two $.post in jQuery

But second $.post return EMPTY value

My jQuery code :

```
var id;
$.post('page.php', {id:id}, function(data){
    var stat;
    $.post('page.php', {stat:stat}, function(newdata){
        alert(newdata);
    });
});
```

And page.php code :

```
if(isset($_POST['stat'])){
    echo "test";
}
```

- In console tab not show Error

Comment: what are you actaully trying to do... this makes no sense

Comment: try this var stat = 1; or assign some value to stats variable

Comment: I have added as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. You need to give value to stats variable.

```
var id;
$.post('page.php', {id:id}, function(data){
    var stat =1;
    $.post('page.php', {stat:stat}, function(newdata){
        alert(newdata);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i have no idea what you are actually trying to do but yes instead of calling two `$.post` to a same page.. you can just pass two post values instead

```
 var id,stat;
 $.post('page.php', {id:id,stat:stat}, function(newdata){
    alert(newdata);
 });
```

page.php (no chnages)

```
if(isset($_POST['stat'])){
  echo "test";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `$.post()` won't send undefined variables, which is the case for your `id` and `stat` variables.

Try to initialize them with any value.

```
var id = 0;
$.post('page.php', {id:id}, function(data){
    var stat = 0;
    $.post('page.php', {stat:stat}, function(newdata){
        alert(newdata);
    });
});
```

The request chaining work form though.